# Using Records with Delphi web services

Tags: delphi, web-services, wsdl, delphi-2009

I'm trying to use records with web services application in Delphi 32, the records defined as

```
TMyRec = record
  Val1:integer;
  Val2:string;
end;

TMyClass = class(TRemotable)
  private fMyRec:TMyRec;
published
  property MyRec:TMyRec read fMyRec write fMyRec;
end;  

ITMyService = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{6283B8DA-C567-4814-906E-321729B1AE72}']

    function GetMyClass(id:Integer):TMyClass;stdcall;
  end;
```

but it doesn't exposed as on WSDL file, so is there problem when using records?

I'm using Delphi 2009

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried [RemObjects SDK](http://www.remobjects.com),and it does the job.

Delphi isn't able to simple things like records inside class for web services :-(, I think they need to work real hard to make Delphi real enterprise tool.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the compiler does not prohibit to publish the record data types, it does not provide the full support for it - see [docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects#Published_Members)

---

**Updated**:

You can always publish the separate fields instead of the whole record:

```
TMyRec = record
  Val1:integer;
  Val2:string;
end;

TMyClass = class(TRemotable)
  private fMyRec:TMyRec;
published
  property MyRecVal1:Integer read GetMyRecVal1 write SetMyRecVal1;
  property MyRecVal1:string read GetMyRecVal2 write SetMyRecVal2;
end;
```

You must implement simple getter and setter methods to access fMyRec fields. I hope that helps, though I am not sure that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Then what I can do expose the records?, I need to expose at least 10 properties and each of them refer to record, or is there something better?

Comment: I Know about that, but I need something like records because it will  contain more than a value, also I have to expose more than 10 records,  which  make it more than 20 or 30 property for just that, which isn't suitable in my case.

Comment: It is also possible to refer to the indivdual fields of a record in the read and write sections of a property declaration: `property Val1: Integer read fMyRec.Val1 write fMyRec.Val1;`